# Specifying Independent Axes Values in Seaborn Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm creating a box plot (more accurately, `boxen` plot) using Seaborn and segmenting the data by one categorical variable. The plots show up fine, however given the different distribution of data based on that category, the y-axis values should be different per individual factor/level of the category. Tableau allows you to specific consistent/unique axes values when segmenting data, and I'd like to do the same. Here's my working code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")

sns.catplot(x="Model", 
            y="Price", 
            kind="boxen", 
            data=df,
            row = "Year",
            height=5,
            aspect=3);
```

Again, the plot looks good, but it's hard to view the span of the box per "row" when each row uses the same range on the Y-axis. Would rather specify a param then create n-box plots manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `sharey=False`, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
df = pd.melt(iris,id_vars=['species'])
sns.catplot(x="species", 
            y="value", 
            kind="boxen", 
            data=df,
            row = "variable",
            height=2,sharey=False,
            aspect=3)
```

[image]